# Обработка данных в jsp

Tags: java, jsp, сервлеты

В общем ситуация такая, на jsp странице есть 2 текстовых поля и кнопка обернутые в тэг `form` в котором прописан `action="another.jsp"`. как мне обработать данные полученные с полей перед переходом на another.jsp. Или при нажатии кнопки данные таки передаются дальше, в сервлет отвечающий за another.jsp?

Comment: Передаются на another.jsp. action обрабатывается браузером. видит там another - отправляет на another. видит same - отправляет на same

Comment: обработать можно в фильтре. можно в action написать same (для примера). в same обработать и отфорвардить в another